# Как узнать новые установленные приложение с помощью Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Я хочу взять лист новых установленных приложений в Iphone. Раньше можно было использовать framework ihasap. (Но с 2016 года его закрыли). Единственное решение это mdm server с over the air архитектурой. Но это очень трудное решение. Кто как выходил из это ситуации, заранее благодарен!!

Comment: А вось поможет. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969923/get-list-of-all-installed-application-in-ios-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой возможности нет. Точнее есть несколько способов, но все они используют запрещенные Apple возможности и такое приложение просто не пройдет модерацию в App Store.